# How do I fix this DirectX error on Windows VMware guest?

Tags: nvidia, vmware, windows-xp

I have VMware player 5.0.2 build-1031769 on Kubuntu 12.04.2 LTS (3.2.0-49-generic) and Graphic card NVIDIA GeForce 310M driver installed.

When I run an application, which plays a sequence of images, on virtual disc with Windows xp as guest the images are not shown and I get a DiretX exception (see attached image DirectX exception). Everytime I run the VMware disc I get a message related to VMware tools -which I have already installed.

Note that on a windows host it works correctly, on Ubuntu/Kubuntu it doesn't.

Perhaps there are issues about NVIDIA Graphic drivers?!

---

[image]

---

[image]

Comment: I don't see much relationship with Ubuntu in your question. It's about VMware specific acceleration fail inside a Windows guest if I understand your question correctly. Consider asking this on http://superuser.com instead.

Comment: On a windows host it works correctly, on Ubuntu/Kubuntu it doesn't.

Comment: That makes a lot of difference for the question! Please include that important detail in your question *by editing it*. And please, next time include those details from the beginning. :)

Comment: You appear to be having a mobile GPU. Is it Optimus enabled by chance? If so, then add more details in your question on how you configured your dual graphics. Googling about it shows a lot of other users having the same issue running Bumblebee.

Comment: It seems my graphic card uses Optimus as it uses CUDA technology.